# How to apply DataGenerator to train and validation data?

Tags: python, data-generation

Using the code here https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#sequence-class, I coded a custom `DataGenerator`.

```
 # Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
 # and `y_set` are the associated classes.

class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

Now, I am wondering how to apply the data Generator to my training data and to the validation data?
I have `X_train` and `X_val`, which are lists containing the image paths to my image files and `y_train` and `y_val`which are one hot encoded labels.

Can I then use this code?

```
training_generator = DataGenerator(X_train, y_train)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(X_val, y_val)
```

And fit the model afterwards?

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the "batch_size" parameter to the `DataGenerator` class initialization method. You could set a default value in the method declaration if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is basically correct. Don't forget to pass the `batch_size` parameter to your `DataGenerator`.

On the other hand, the `epochs` parameter (as you mentioned in comment) should be passed to `model.fit_generator` (better yet, use `model.fit` instead because the `fit_generator` method is [deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator)). If you don't pass it the default value of `epochs` would be 1.

Also please check out [this tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) on how to use the `Sequence` class (you can jump to the bottom where the `DataGenerator` is used). In this tutorial, a couple of parameters other than `batch_size` are passed to `DataGenerator` because they are defined as input of the `__init__` method. You don't have to pass them as long as you don't define them.

Comment: Ok, thank you! :-) Another problem arose because the generator could not find the files... Can you maybe take a look to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451843/datagenerator-does-not-find-the-files-in-google-drive It is related to this question here...