# DataGenerator does not find the Files in Google Drive

Tags: python, error-handling, file-not-found

Using the code here https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#sequence-class, I coded a custom DataGenerator.

```
# Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
 # and `y_set` are the associated classes.

class DataGenerator(Sequence):
def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
    self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
    self.batch_size = batch_size

def __len__(self):
    return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
    self.batch_size]
    batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
    self.batch_size]

    return np.array([
        resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224))
           for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

I have `X_train` and `X_val`, which are lists containing the image paths to my image files and y_train and y_valwhich are one hot encoded labels and applied this data to the `DataGenerator`.

```
training_generator = DataGenerator(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(X_val, y_val, batch_size=32)
```

And fit the model afterwards:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // batch_size,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // batch_size,
                    epochs = 10,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    workers=6)
```

When running this code, I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-411e62536182> in <module>()
      5                     epochs = 10,
      6                     use_multiprocessing=True,
----> 7                     workers=6)

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageio/core/request.py in _parse_uri(self, uri)
    271                 # Reading: check that the file exists (but is allowed a dir)
    272                 if not os.path.exists(fn):
--> 273                     raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
    274             else:
    275                 # Writing: check that the directory to write to does exist

FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/2017-IWT4S-CarsReId_LP-dataset/s01_l01/1_1.png'
```

`X_train` is a list which contains the absolute file path to my data in the Google Drive as a string.

```
X_train[0]
'/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/2017-IWT4S-CarsReId_LP-dataset/s01_l01/1_1.png'
```

How do I have to modify the code in order to make the generator find my files?
Is that maybe because the Colab Notebook file and the data are not in the same folder? -> I pu my Colab Jupyter Notebook in the folder "/content/gdrive/My Drive" and I also got the FileNotFoundError".
Or do I have to route anyhow to the correct folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to a Google Drive TimeOut. I solved this issue by writing in my console as recommended here: [FileNotFoundError: No such file: -> Error occuring due to TimeOut of Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468830/filenotfounderror-no-such-file-error-occuring-due-to-timeout-of-google-driv)

```
function ConnectButton(){
    console.log("Connect pushed"); 
    document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click() 
}
setInterval(ConnectButton,600);
```